# Integer solutions for this equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the integers (or at least natural numbers)$x_1$ and $x_2$ which satisfy this equation:

$3x_1 + 7x_2 = 1000$.

And is there a name for such a problem?

Comment: Cf. [linear Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations)

Comment: It is worth noting that $\gcd(3,7)=1$ so there exist integers $y_1,y_2$ such that $3y_1+7y_2 = 1$.  You can find for instance that $y_1=-2$ and $y_2=1$ works for this.  Multiplying by $1000$ gives a solution to the original equation.  Further solutions can be found by noting that $3\cdot 7 + 7\cdot (-3)=0$... so the full set of solutions $(x_1,x_2)$ is $\{(-2000+7t,1000-3t)~:~t\in\Bbb Z\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [linear Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations).

From the Bezout relation $3(-2)+7(1)=1$, we have $3(-2000)+7(1000)=1000$.

Generally, $3(-2000+7k)+7(1000-3k)=3(-2000)+7(1000)=1000$.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your help !